# Send to different emails based on ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to have my contact form send to different emails based on the department the user chooses. Right now I'm just trying to print the department the user has picked but I'd like to set up some conditionals to send to different emails based on the department value.

This gives me `KeyError at /contact/ 'DEALERSHIP ENQUIRIES'`

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms 

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    DEPARTMENT_CHOICES = (
        ('SALES ENQUIRIES', 'Sales Enquiuries'),
        ('DEALERSHIP ENQUIRIES', 'Dealership Enquiuries'),
        ('JOB ENQUIRIES', 'Job Enquiuries'),
        ('ALL OTHER QUESTIONS', 'All Other Questions'),
    )
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    sender_email = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    department = forms.ChoiceField(choices = DEPARTMENT_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 8}))
```

**views.py**

```
def contact_view(request):
    form = ContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = f'Message from {form.cleaned_data["name"]}'
            message = form.cleaned_data["message"]
            sender = form.cleaned_data["sender_email"]
            phone = form.cleaned_data["phone"]
            department = form.cleaned_data["department"]
            print(form.cleaned_data[department])

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name='main/contact.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Are you sure it is `print(form.cleaned_data[department])` and not `print(form.cleaned_data['department'])` (so use `'department'` as key, not the `department` variable)?

Comment: Wow I must be tired.. Thank you!